# how to get new records from MySQL using java

Tags: java, mysql

I am working with Java and MySQL. I wrote code in Java. I have 10000 rows and 5 columns(id,name,address,contactNo and status) in MySQL table.
I wrote code for updating the contactNo in table.
I have created the jar for my class and it is working fine. Jar is working properly on the command prompt.

---

Here I am running the query as follows:

```
select id,name,address,status from student where status = 0 limit 0,50
```

after getting records updated, I am setting the status=1,so it will execute continuously.

---

I am updating the 10,000 records, so when I try to run jar on two command prompt, here I am getting the issue:

records which are getting updated on first command prompt, the same records are getting updated on second command prompt, but I don't want the same records to be updated on second command prompt.

How do I get the new records updated on the second command prompt?

Comment: I'm not SURE, but - I would guess larger font-size doesn't automatically make your question get answered faster.  If it does though, let me know! ;)

Comment: Why would you start two processes on the command line?  I don't understand the status=1 making something(?) run continuously.

Comment: @Dave: I corrected it. I think this was a markdown bug. Obviously a paragraph immediately followed by a line (---) causes the text above it to appear huge.

Comment: @DJ31 - cool :)  no worries - was just giving you a hard time.  (I wasn't the one who marked your answer down btw - I don't know java, so - it could be an awesome question for all I know)

Comment: @DJ31, please provide code, we cannot answer your question without that.

Comment: my guess is it's not committing the changes, but without more info I can't be sure

Comment: What does it mean: "after getting records updated, I am setting the status=1,so it will execute continuously. " ? What execute continuously? Select, Application, Display of records, ... ? What the reason? "records which are getting updated on first command prompt, the same records are getting updated on second command prompt, but I don't want the same records to be updated on second command prompt" ? Where is query for update? Which relation has query select? Could you please give more code?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you code to help solve your problem when you haven't provided any, but I can tell you that your stated issue is due to the fact that your SQL string returns the same 50 records every time. You probably do not need to batch your updates for just 10,000 records, so running a single update is probably sufficient. If you disagree or do not understand, then please provide your code so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

The 'logic' seems to be working as you intended.

the question is why are you trying to run the same update statement twice on the same data set?

I would suggest you clearly articulate what you are trying to update on each instance of the application, and make it different that the other one, then you will not have multiple of the same application updating the same rows.

or...

just don't run the same app twice and expect something different to occur.